# what's wrong with my .bat file?

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to `xcopy` a folder with all sub folders and files into another folder which is named as the current date and time

This is what I have:

```
xcopy  C:\Users\t\Desktop\survival\world "C:\Users\t\Desktop\backups\survival\Backup-%date:/=/%_%time:~0,2%:%time:~3,2% /s /e /i
```

can anyone help me?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
%time:~0,2%:%time:~3,2%
           ^....You can not have a colon in a file name
```

Also, you are missing a closing quote at the end of the target folder

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion 

    set "source=C:\Users\t\Desktop\survival\world"
    set "target=C:\Users\t\Desktop\backups\survival\Backup"

:loop
    set "timeStamp=%date:/=/%_%time:~0,2%:%time:~3,2%"
    xcopy "%source%\." "%target%-%timeStamp%" /s /e /i
    ping -n 601 "" >nul 
    goto :loop
```

Comment: xcopy  C:\Users\t\Desktop\survival\world "C:\Users\t\Desktop\backups\survival\Backup-%date:/=/%_%time:~0,2%.%time:~3,2% /s /e /i

Comment: @trebor97351, sorry, I had to leave the keyboard for a moment. Close the opening quote

Comment: i just realised it contains a "/" and you cant have that in a file name either

Comment: @trebor97351, the inner slashes will be considered backslashes and folder structure created as the `/i` has been included indicating that the target is a folder.

Comment: this is the code now  :loop
xcopy  C:\Users\t\Desktop\survival\world C:\Users\t\Desktop\backups\survival\Backup-%date:/=-%_%time:~0,2%.%time:~3,2% /s /e /i
PING -n 601 127.0.0.1>nul
goto loop

Comment: @trebor97351, at least for my locale, the  `%time%` variable is space prefixed from ` 0:00` to ` 9:59`. Handle it or keep the quotes around the target folder